# How to bind text based on a map in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to bind text according to a certain map. For example

HTML

```
<div>{A: alpha, B: bravo, C: charlie, D: delta.....}[myKey]</div>
```

OUTPUT

```
<div>alpha</div> //if myKey is 'A'
<div>bravo>/div> //if myKey is 'B'
<div>charlie>/div> //if myKey is 'C'
<div>delta>/div> //if myKey is 'D'

And so on...
```

The above works for binding 'class' but not for 'text'.

I don't want to pollute the controller by making a map in my scope like this

```
$scope.map = {A: alpha, B: bravo, C: charlie, D: delta...}
<div>{{map[myKey]}}</div>
```

so that UI logic remains in the UI layer.

Is there a way to do this using only built-in Angular directives? I don't want to write a custom directive if I don't need to.

Comment: ngSwitch? stack overflow made me write more words.

Comment: You mean using only built-in AngularJS directives?

Comment: @haimlit ngSwitch does work but smelly as it creates a lot of fluff.

Comment: If not ngSwitch then you have ngIf and conditions in angular expressions, such as {{ myKey === 'A' ? alpha : ''}}. Let's assume you can write a directive that will be built in angular, what would be its usage that would be better than ngIf or ngSwitch?

Comment: I'd love to see this working <div ng-bind-text-with-map="{A: alpha, B: bravo, C: charlie, D: delta}[myKey]"></div> OR <div>{A: alpha, B: bravo, C: charlie, D: delta}[myKey]</div>

Comment: @pickhunter Why do you only want to use built-in stuff? Writing your own directive is rather easy.  Is there a technical constraint? or just you're not familiar with directives?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I saw this syntax working for binding classnames so I wondered if there is anything to bind text this way as well. Of course a directive is a last resort solution, but I thought there would be something inbuilt for a task as trivial as this.

Comment: Just ensure that it's a valid angular expression, and everything will work fine. http://jsbin.com/nibumibe/1/

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks, it was exactly I was looking for. One caveat for text values, the map has to have quotes around the string values. It works for binding class names without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngInit` if you really want to, but this really belongs in a controller.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5gnCP9nJXHQQF7t9Ea2)

```
<div ng-init="myKey='A'; map={A: 'alpha', B: 'bravo'}">{{map[myKey]}}</div>
```

This is not the best practice, but it's closest to what you are asking for that I can think of.

Comment: This works but again as you said it pollutes the controller with view logic.